# How to delete a row from a table in powerpoint using Python?

Tags: python

The code is iterating each cell in a table in python and trying to delete blank rows from table in powerpoint using python. I am not able to delete the row or hide the row which has no data. Any solution please ??

```
for i in range (1,4):
        r = table.rows[i]
        for j in range(0,1):
                c = r.cells[j]
                if c.text_frame.text == "":

                    del r
```

Comment: You want to edit the original content or edit the copy of original content?

Comment: what's table? Please post something which can be reproduced or understood

Comment: to start with, "for j in range(0,1) will only" return 0

Comment: The upper index of the `range()`  method is never used. `list(range(0,1)) == [0]` and `list(range(0,3)) == [0, 1, 2]`